# django next url not working correctly

Tags: python, django

I have created a login page using default django(1.9.5) auth_view and the urls.py looks like this

```
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {"template_name": 'login.html'}, name='login'),
```

and used the django specified html to generate the form and the html looks like this

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}?next={{next}}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <table class="login-form">
                <tr>
                    <td class="input-label">{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
                    <td class="input-field"><input class="form-control" id="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}" maxlength="30" name="{{ form.username.html_name }}" type="text" /> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="input-label">{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
                    <td class="input-field"><input class="form-control" id="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}" maxlength="30" name="{{ form.password.html_name }}" type="password" /> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                {# Assumes you setup the password_reset view in your URLconf #}
                <p class="pull-left"><a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Forgot password?</a></p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right"/>
                    Sign in <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></span>
                </button>
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}"/>
            </form>
```

Now if any user tries to visit a page like /admin and user is not authenticated, user is redirected to /login and after successful login he should be redirected to /admin as per user request. but I am landing in /login/admin instead. Where am I going wrong,

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try `action="."` or `action="{% url 'login' %}"`,

Comment: I didnt write any view for login, view is coming from django auth_view. I dont know how redirect is handled there

Answer (score 1):

Don't use query parameter in the action, set your action of the form like

```
action="{% url 'login' %}"
```

and you are already using `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}"/>` in your code which will handle the `next` of your url.

Answer (score -1):

SOLUTION:
   I have found why it didnt work, In my middleware I was doing lstrip('/') which is removing / before admin. which means when I try to login the url will look like http://localhost:8000/login?/next=admin/ instead of
http://localhost:8000/login/?next=/admin/